# How does the browser determine which srcset image to load when no sizes attribute is present?

Tags: html, css, image, web

I have an image that gets displayed in various sizes on my website:

- The website is responsive and the apparent image size is often the size of the browser, with some exceptions when the browser is very wide. So, the image's width can vary between 200 and over 1000 pixels.
- We want the image to be displayed in native resolution on high-resolution devices (Retina).

So, our image is present in three resolutions, let's call them `i1.png`, `i2.png` and `i3.png`.

What I would like to do is just this:

```
<img src="i1.png" srcset="i1.png 420w, i2.png 840w, i3.png 1260w" />
```

In my opinion, the browser should have enough information to figure out which image it needs.

- On a standard-resolution device (no retina screen), it just takes the width of the `<img />` element and then loads the image that has a width higher or equal to the width of the element. E.g. if the image element is 600px wide, then it will load `i2.png`.
- On a retina device, it would just multiply the width of the `<img />` element with the device-pixel ratio. E.g. on a "2x" device, it would load `i3.png` for a 600px image, because `2 x 600 = 1200`, so it would need the image with a width of `1260px`.

It seems the browser indeed does something like that, but in some cases it would load the `840px` image even though the `420px` image would be enough.

**What factors does the browser use to determine the size of the image to load?**

- Is it using CSS rules to determine the image's apparent width?
- Or does it ignore CSS and just look at `width` and `height` attributes on the `<img />`, if present?
- What if some parts of CSS are not yet loaded?

Crucial point: I do not want to use the `sizes` attribute, because I would need media queries for all possible combinations of device-pixel ratios and browser window widths. This should not be necessary, because as I said, the browser should have enough information.

I checked the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) about the topic, but they say that if `sizes` is omitted, then we need to use `2x` descriptors (instead of `420w` descriptors) in the `srcset` attribute. This is useless for my scenario: the goal is to have the browser find out which image to load, not just based on device-pixel ratio, but also based on responsiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the browser does not respect any CSS to decide which image to load. After all, it is not clear which CSS files have already been loaded when the image starts loading.

Instead, it treats each image as if it was stretched to the full page width. If the screen is non-retina and 600px wide, it would load the next-higher image size (840px in the above example), regardless of the actual size that the image would occupy on the screen.

For retina screens, it would just multiply the required image width by the device-pixel ratio.